# index.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined at loadQuiz (index.js:33)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a small problem in index.js file. Next question should come up when submit button is clicked. but instead this error is showing up...

> index.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined
> at loadQuiz (index.js:33)
> at HTMLButtonElement. (index.js:43)

Use snippet to view the result

```js
const quizContent = [{
  question: "What is the most used programming language ?",
  a: "Java",
  b: "Python",
  c: "C",
  d: "C++",
  answer: "a"
}, {
  question: "How much time is required to become a Web Developer?",
  a: "1 month",
  b: "2 month",
  c: "3 month",
  d: "4 month",
  answer: "d"

}];

const questionEl = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;
loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz() {
  const currentQuizContent = quizContent[currentQuiz];

  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizContent.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.d;

  currentQuiz++;
}
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentQuiz++;
  loadQuiz();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
  background: #bbd2c5;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-quiz {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-quiz li {
  padding: 6px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #4370e7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #3259c5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-quiz">
    <div>
      <h2 id="question">Question</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a">
          <label id="a_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b">
          <label id="b_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c">
          <label id="c_text" for="c">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d">
          <label id="d_text" for="d">Question Text</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `currentQuiz` twice, in the event listener and inside `loadQuiz()` function. Besides you should only increment `currentQuiz` while it's less than `quizContent` length.

Answer (score 1):

`currentQuiz` is incrementing two times. (inside the submit as well as loadQuiz)

```js
const quizContent = [{
  question: "What is the most used programming language ?",
  a: "Java",
  b: "Python",
  c: "C",
  d: "C++",
  answer: "a"
}, {
  question: "How much time is required to become a Web Developer?",
  a: "1 month",
  b: "2 month",
  c: "3 month",
  d: "4 month",
  answer: "d"

}];

const questionEl = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;
loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz() {
  const currentQuizContent = quizContent[currentQuiz];

  if(currentQuizContent) {
  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizContent.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.d;

  currentQuiz++;
 }
}
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loadQuiz();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
  background: #bbd2c5;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-quiz {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-quiz li {
  padding: 6px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #4370e7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #3259c5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-quiz">
    <div>
      <h2 id="question">Question</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a">
          <label id="a_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b">
          <label id="b_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c">
          <label id="c_text" for="c">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d">
          <label id="d_text" for="d">Question Text</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra `currentQuiz++;` in the event listener

```js
const quizContent = [{
  question: "What is the most used programming language ?",
  a: "Java",
  b: "Python",
  c: "C",
  d: "C++",
  answer: "a"
}, {
  question: "How much time is required to become a Web Developer?",
  a: "1 month",
  b: "2 month",
  c: "3 month",
  d: "4 month",
  answer: "d"

}];

const questionEl = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;
loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz() {
  const currentQuizContent = quizContent[currentQuiz];

  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizContent.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.d;

  currentQuiz++;
}
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentQuiz++;
  loadQuiz();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
  background: #bbd2c5;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #292e49, #536976, #bbd2c5);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-quiz {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-quiz li {
  padding: 6px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #4370e7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #3259c5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Secular+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-quiz">
    <div>
      <h2 id="question">Question</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a">
          <label id="a_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b">
          <label id="b_text" for="a">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c">
          <label id="c_text" for="c">Question Text</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d">
          <label id="d_text" for="d">Question Text</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If it helped and loved your problem, please mark as an answer for future viewers

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `currentQuiz++` from the loadQuiz function. You only need to increment when click the submit button not when the function is called.

Your function should stay like this:

```
function loadQuiz() {
  const currentQuizContent = quizContent[currentQuiz];

  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizContent.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizContent.d;

}
```